# Is there a way to disable hyphenation in the preamble for a word containing dashes

Tags: hyphenation, pandoc

I am writing a document where I commonly use a word that contains a dash ("Foo-Bar"). I want to globally disable hyphenation for this word. Is this possible? I am looking for a solution that I can use in the document preamble. I know that I can setup hyphenations in the document preamble using the `\hyphenation` command, and that I can completely disable hyphenation for a given word by using this command and then not including any dashes. But I don't know how to disable hyphenation for a word that itself contains dashes.

The main document itself is written in Markdown (and converted to LaTeX and other formats using Pandoc) so the typical solution of defining a new command (`\def\FooBar{\mbox{Foo-Bar}}`) wouldn't work -- that's why I am looking for a solution that can be implemented in the document preamble.

Comment: `\exhyphenpenalty=10000`

Comment: @DavidCarlisle Does that allow me to disable hyphenation for a specific single word ?

Comment: no, it disables hyphenation at explicit -

Comment: @DavidCarlisle I see. Not specifically what I was looking for, but could be a solution if I cannot do it for a single word. Thanks.

Comment: if you use luatex you could do a single word globally, for pdftex you need to convince pandoc to generate `\mbox{foo-bar}`  or just add one line to your build script after calling pandoc, to run `sed -e 's/foo-bar/\\mbox{foo-bar}/g'` not everything has to be done in tex

Comment: @DavidCarlisle That's good advice as well. If you can post this (both the exhyphenpenalty and that sed option) as an answer, I'll accept it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could set

```
\exhyphenpenalty=10000
```

Which would disable all hyphenation at an explicit `-` within the scope of that setting.

If you use luatex you could do a single word globally, as it allows a syntax to specify literal `-` in hyphenation patterns or you could use the `input_buffer` callback to globally replace `foo-bar` by `\mbox{foo-bar}`

For pdftex you need to convince pandoc to generate `\mbox{foo-bar}` or just add one line to your build script after calling pandoc, to run

```
sed -i -e 's/foo-bar/\\mbox{foo-bar}/g' file.tex
```

Not everything has to be done in tex.